# Unresolved reference to symbol in WiX (LGHT0094) (No illegal characters?)

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I have searched here for answers but as every case seems to be unique and so far no answers helped me, I decided to post my own. For some reason I am getting the following error about the following code. I can't seem to find anything wrong with it. It has no illegal characters as far as I can see. I've tried with and without the " and it doesn't make a difference. The line specifically referenced in the error is the verb line.

**Error:**

```
C:\Users\kylec\Desktop\SampleFirst\SampleFirst.wxs(25) : error LGHT0094 : 
Unresolved reference to symbol 'File:Viewer.exe' in section 
'Product:{00000000-0000-0000-0000000000000000}'.
```

**Code:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
  <Product Name='Viewer 1.0' Id='PUT-GUID-HERE' UpgradeCode='PUT-GUID-HERE'
    Language='1033' Codepage='1252' Version='1.0.0' Manufacturer='Direct'>
    <Package Id='*' Keywords='Installer' Description="Installer"
      Comments='Installer is a registered trademark of Direct' 
      Manufacturer='Direct' InstallerVersion='100' Languages='1033' 
      Compressed='yes' SummaryCodepage='1252' />

    <Media Id='1' Cabinet='Sample.cab' EmbedCab='yes' DiskPrompt="CD-ROM #1" />
    <Property Id='DiskPrompt' Value="Installation [1]" />

    <Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
      <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder' Name='PFiles'>
        <Directory Id='DataMotionDirect' Name='DMD'>
          <Directory Id='INSTALLDIR' Name='Viewer'>

           <Component Id='MainExecutable' Guid='*'>
               <Shortcut Id="startmenuViewer" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" 
                         Name="Viewer" WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' 
                         Icon="Viewer.exe" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
                <Shortcut Id="desktopViewer" Directory="DesktopFolder" 
                          Name="Viewer" WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' 
                          Icon="Viewer.exe" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />

              <File Id='EXE' Name='Viewer.exe' DiskId='1' 
                    Source='Viewer.exe' KeyPath='yes'>
              </File>
        <ProgId Id="DMDCCDAV" Description="Viewer">
          <Extension Id="xml" >
            <Verb Id="open" Argument="&quot;%1&quot;" TargetFile="Viewer.exe" />
          </Extension>
        </ProgId>
            </Component>

          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>

      <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder" Name="Programs">
       <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDir" Name="Viewer">
        <Component Id="ProgramMenuDir" Guid="*">
         <RemoveFolder Id='ProgramMenuDir' On='uninstall' />
         <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]' 
                        Type='string' Value='' KeyPath='yes' />
        </Component>
       </Directory>
      </Directory>

      <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop" />
    </Directory>

    <Feature Id='Complete' Level='1'>
      <ComponentRef Id='MainExecutable' />
      <ComponentRef Id='ProgramMenuDir' />
    </Feature>

    <Icon Id="Viewer.exe" SourceFile="Viewer.exe" />

  </Product>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is referencing that code (i.e that's at line 25)?  I'm seeing nothing relating to "Viewer.exe" in that code snippet.

Comment: Oops updated question. Forgot I changed the executable name.

Comment: Where have you defined a `File` element (in `Component`) with `Name` or `Id` of "Viewer.exe"?

Comment: @PeterRitchie I have updated my question to include the entrie component. Its ID is MainExecutable but contains a File with name Viewer.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the piece of source code you specified it is not clear what actual string wix references in fact. Would you kindly either highlight the string or post the entire file?

Ok then after you posted your entire file I see the problematic line. You must use file ID instead of file name there.

Comment: Ok, at least I see where the problem comes from. TargetFile must be an ID of a file you added to file table previously. See the doc on Verb element: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/verb.html

Comment: But not the file name.

Comment: Oh so it should be something like this then? <Extension Id="xml" >
      <Verb Id="open" Argument="&quot;%1&quot;" TargetFile="EXE" />
     </Extension>

Comment: I presume - yes. The last time I had been in touch with WiX it was 2006.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Wix set up to try this, but you can try to move the **Shortcut element** up to be nested under the **Component element** and not the **File element**. Then set the **WorkingFolder attribute**. Try something like [this](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/create_start_menu_shortcut.html).

Like I said, I can't compile and test, but try to set the **Target attribute** to: 
**Target="[#Viewer.exe]"**

```
<Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut" 
          Name="My Application Name" 
          Description="My Application Description"
          Target="[#Viewer.exe]"
          WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR"/>
```

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately I got the same error.

Comment: Ok I tried that and got the same error. Keep in mind though that the line referenced is the verb line.